React router dom changes the url but not the view in dynamic routing
I am having trouble changing the view in react with routing.
i want to have dynamic route for each product, url is changing but the page is not getting redirected
here's my code for App.js
import "./styles.css";
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";

import { Navbar } from "./components/Navbar";
import { Home } from "./pages/Home";
import { List } from "./pages/List";
import { Contact } from "./pages/Contact";
import { ItemDetails } from "./pages/ItemDetails";

export default function App() {
  // add dynamic route to the list route below
  const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
      path: "/",
      element: <Navbar />,
      children: [
        { index: true, element: <Home /> },
        { path: "/contact", element: <Contact /> },
        {
          path: "/list",
          element: <List />,
          children: [{ path: ":id", element: <ItemDetails /> }],
        },
      ],
    },
  ]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </div>
  );
}




and then here's my list.jsx
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import { items } from "../data";

export const List = () => {
  return (
    <div className="list page">
      <h3>List page</h3>
      <div className="item-list">
        {items.map((i) => (
          <div className="item" key={i.id}>
            {/* add link to item details here */}
            <NavLink to={i.id}>{i.name}</NavLink>
            <img src={i.image} alt={i.name} />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};



when navigating to this url is changing, expected to see the route in
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { itemDetailsData } from "../data";

export const ItemDetails = () => {
  const { itemId } = useParams();
  console.log(itemId);
  const item = itemDetailsData.find((i) => i.id === itemId);
  if (!item) {
    return <h3> Item details not found.</h3>;
  }
  return (
    <div className="item-details page">
      <h1>{item.name}</h1>
      <img src={item.image} alt={item.name} />
      <ul className="specs">
        {item.specs.map((spec, i) => (
          <li key={i}>{spec}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>

      <p>{item.description}</p>
    </div>
  );
};


but it is not displayed!

Hi, are you getting any errors in your browser console?

No, i was just missing an outlet in List element :))
